# Slowdowns while using Firefox

Tags: 11.04, firefox

I have Windows 7 and Natty installed on my computer. There is no problem on Windows 7's side, but whenever I log into Natty, it slows down while using Firefox 4.

I tried it in normal mode using Unity and classic mode. However, the result is the same: it slows down e.g. when I scroll, it takes time to get effect, and also when I click other tabs, it takes time to active them. Moreover I cannot type properly, due to the lag.

I don't know what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to CCSM (compiz Configuration Settings Manager) then go to the OpenGL plug in and then uncheck **Sync to Vblank**.

Then go back and on the Composite plug in uncheck **Detect Refresh Rate**