# Which should I use on HP machine with AMD phenom x3: 32-bit or 64-bit?

Tags: 11.04, unity, 64-bit, 32-bit, architecture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between 32bit and 64 bit and which should I chose?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-is-the-difference-between-32bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-chose)

I installed Ubuntu Natty 64-bit on HP machine, with the following hardware:

- AMD Phenom 8600 triple core processor
- 3GB RAM
- GeForce 6150SE nForce 430

But I feel that it's so slow compared with the same machine with Ubuntu Lucid 32-bit with PAE.

What do you recommend, install Natty 32-bit? Get back to Lucid or Maverick?

Some tip for speed up my machine? Should I install gnome?

Comment: It's the same, and, it feels slow because of some COmpiz settings that slow down the machine, and you already have Gnome, Unity is Gnome, it's just a shell on top of it.

Comment: ok, but there is a way to get better performance?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41135/slowdowns-while-using-firefox/41140#41140

Answer (score 0):

Try installing preload and prelink. they are both in the default repositories. Check out this guide for prelinking: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=74197

Comment: btw, this is for speeding up the machine.